# speed of USB 3 when connected to several USB 2 devices

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I am wondering what is the speed of a USB 3 hub when 2 or more USB 2 are connected to it?

to be more specific:

Assume that I have a USB 3 device which is connected to say 2 USB camera. Each USB camera sends data at the speed of around 40M bps. when I have a camera working at 40m bps, it works properly, but when I have two of them, I need to reduce the camera speed to 20M bps otherwise my PC crashes.

The hub is a USB3 and I am sure it can cope with 40m bps, but why my system crashes when two camera is connected to it?

what is standard says about when a USB 3 hub is connected to a USB 2 device?

Comment: A usb2 hub will "downgrade" to usb1 if a usb1 device is connected. I assume the same thing happens with usb3<>usb2

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that the problem you are experience is because the USB3 driver for your system has a bug in it when trying to handle a hub with more than one device attached. It is probably not because of the combined bandwidth of the additional USB2 device. That is just my guess.

Comment: I am using windows 7. Do you think it has a bug?